# jQuery load() function not setting global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not too sure why but I figured someone out here can educate me a bit on this. I am looking to set a global variable based off a jQuery loaded object. In my case I am loading an original image size from the server so I can proportionally resize it programatically.  But I am stumped as to why I can alert or console log the height and width but cannot set a variable to those retrieved values outside the callback function?

```
HTML:
<img src='someimage.jpg' />

JS/jQuery:
var imgHeight, imgWidth;

$("img").load(function() {
    imgHeight = $(this).height();
    imgWidth = $(this).width();
    console.log(imgWidth + " x " + imgHeight); // this works
});

console.log(imgWidth + " x " + imgHeight); // this does not
```

Is this a timing issue and what would be a better solution to load the image and set a variable based on that response?

Comment: That is because you are using $(this).width(); within the function

Comment: `load` is asynchronous so in the 2nd example your code is trying to log vars that are empty because it is run before `load` has completed.

Comment: It has nothing to do with scope, only with timing. You are trying to access the values **before** they have been set.

Comment: Check the answer to this SO question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached. As per jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), the `jQuery.load()` event can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache.

Comment: So basically the load is happening after the rest of the code or before the rest? is the console log within the function first or second?

Comment: Can't you find this out by simply looking at the console? In which order do the `console.log` statements appear?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `.load` function runs once the image has been loaded. The `console.log` outside of load is trying to log variables that have no value.